# How to add status information while a javascript program is running?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `HTML5` document with these scripts in `<head>`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.example.com/run_program.js"></script>
```

To run the program in `<body>` I use

```
<div><input type="button" onclick="retrieveData()" value="Execute Query"></div>
```

The `run_program.js` sometimes takes 20 seconds to complete.

How can I add a simple control to let the user know that the processes is running?

Comment: Start this at the top of your function: http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/. Stop it at the end.

Comment: you won't occasionally need the spin.js plugin. since we don't know your run_program.js, we can't help you.
but the idea would be, to create some messages inside your js, to inform the user about the current process state...

Comment: @Rory Need a bit more help. Do I add this to run_program.js or do I load this as a separate script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you wanna get  but AFAICU you can use HTML5 [progress](http://caniuse.com/#search=progress) element and change it's 'value' property while you program running (e.g. if there is loop in your program, you can add 100/(total iterations) every iteration).

```html
<progress id="running" min="0" max="100" value="0"></progress>
```